# jQuery success function not executing

Tags: php, jquery

the first success function works, the second doesnt... it works if I change datatype to text... but if i change datatype to text am not able to iterate through the array .. for example i require data[0].. which works with json....but with json success function is not working ...

```
var turl = "getForum.php";
var turl = "getForum.php";
var wurl = "getDiscussions.php";
$.ajax({
    url:turl,
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
        forumid = data[0]; // this works ...
        dataString = 'forumid='+ forumid;
        $.ajax({
            url:wurl,
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data:dataString,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data); // this works if I change datatype to text... but if i type datatype to   text am not able to iterate through the array .. for example i require data[0].. which works with json....but with json success function is not working ... 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

php file return json object

```
$query1 = " select * from discussforum where forumId= '$forumid'; ";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1); 

 while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 )){
 echo json_encode($info1);
 }
```

Comment: Could you please correct the indentation of your script? It is very hard to read like this...

Comment: It just looks like `getDiscussions.php` doesn't return JSON

Comment: Probably because there is an error. Add also an error part:
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
And Musa is probably correct. Use Firebux to detect a response after your ajax request. Fiddler is also a good option for ajax debugging.

Comment: Also take a look a this video tutorial. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4jXAaEMp2M

Comment: console.log(dataString); can you plz suggest what this will output from your first ajax success function in first ajax call

Comment: use jsonlint.com to validate returned json which you can copy directly from ajax request response in browser console. Also if you were to implement some AJAX error handling you would have a lot more info before coming here

Comment: @Jai it returns what is desirable .... forumid=107

Comment: @RPM i included header('application/json') at the top of my php script ... still success function doesnt work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about your PHP is returning only one JSON object? If not:

```
$ret = array();
while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 )){
    $ret[] = $info1;
}
print json_encode($ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is delineated in the comments, but here it goes in a bit more detail. First take a look at the fine documentation for [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You need to add an error callback to all your Ajax calls. with the following signature:

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

You can just add a parameter to .ajax() like this:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.error(textStatus);
},
```

This way you will see in the console every error that happens during the Ajax call and also during the processing of the message. You can define a generic ajaxError callback in some common .js file and use it everywhere.

In this case you are explaining very well the cause of the error: what `getDiscussions.php`is returning is not a JSON, and thus the jQuery parser cannot understand it when you set `dataType:"json"`: it would call the `error` callback if there was one. It works however when the dataType is set to text. So the POST request is probably failing.

To see what it is sending you can just extract it in the error callback, like this:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.error('Error in response: ' + jqXHR.responseText
},
```

so you can diagnose the problem in the server.